# Button onClick using .jade with a JS function

Tags: javascript, pug

I am trying to use a function for a button onClick in my .jade file. The function is in a javascript file. I want to use the screenshots function whenever the button is clicked. My question is am I importing the .js file correctly? Also, am I calling the function correctly?

When I run, this is the error that I am getting:

```
Invalid or unexpected token on the line button(onClick = # 
{screenshots(client)}) GO
```

Index.jade

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  script (src='../scripts/screenshot.js')
  p Welcome to #{title}
  button(onClick = #{screenshots(client)}) GO
  div.Windows
    img(src="http://localhost:3000/images/myscreenshot2.png", class="image", width="20%", height="20%")  
    object(data="http://localhost:3000/test.txt",class = "texttest",width='50%', height='615px' display: block;)
```

screenshot.js

```
async function screenshots(client) {
    await client.takeScreenshot().then(
client.saveScreenshot("./public/images/myscreenshot2.png")
);
}


async function connection () {

    const wdio = require("webdriverio");
    const assert = require("assert");

const opts = {
    port: 4723,
    capabilities: {
        platformName: "Android",
        platformVersion: '8.1',
        deviceName: "emulator-5554",
        app: "C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\test.apk",
        automationName: "UiAutomator2"
    }
};
    const fs = require('fs');   
    const client = await wdio.remote(opts);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from mixing server-side pug/jade and client-side JavaScript.

Let's focus on your button code:

```
button(onClick = #{screenshots(client)}) GO
```

The `#{}` is a pug instruction to insert the value of a variable into that space.  At the time the button is pressed you just want it to call a local script, and no pug/jade is needed for that:

```
button(onClick= "screenshots(client)") GO
```

The error code you get is due to trying to call a function where pug/jade is expecting an expression that it can evaluate to a string.

I can't be sure as I don't know how your file system is set up, but you probably need to reference the script using an absolute path:

```
script (src='/scripts/screenshot.js')
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now that I changed the button to button(onClick = "screenshots(client)") Go I get the error: screenshots is not defined. Is this the correct way to import?   script (src='../scripts/screenshot.js')

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab in your browser to see if that file has loaded correctly?  That should tell you what's happening.  I just gave you a tip in an edit to the answer.

Comment: I did not have the file inside my public so it was not finding it. Thanks for the help!